# rascal etymology

Tags: etymology, latin, spanish

I use the word rascal (as in troublemaker) to describe my 7-month old daughter. My father in law (from Costa Rica) recently used the Spanish word "rascar" (rascarse) meaning to scratch, which is something that she loves doing.

Is that a possible origin of the word rascal?

Answer (score 12):

[Rascal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rascal)

> Etymology
>
> Recorded since c.1330, as Middle English rascaile (“people of the lowest class, rabble of an army”), derived from 12th century Old French rascaille (“outcast, rabble”) (modern French racaille), perhaps from rasque (“mud, filth, scab, dregs”), from Vulgar Latin *rasicō (“to scrape”). The singular form is first attested in 1461; the present extended sense of "low, dishonest person" is from early 1586.

[Rascar](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rascar#Spanish)

> Etymology
>
> From Old Spanish rascar, from Vulgar Latin *rāsicāre, a frequentative verb based on Latin rāsus (“shaven”).

Apparently both are based on [rās- (“shaven”)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Latin/rasico), (Disclaimer on page: This Latin entry contains reconstructed terms and roots. As such, the term(s) in this entry are not directly attested, but are hypothesized to have existed based on comparative evidence).

Comment: Thank you, this further research is really interesting, and thanks for the note on the epistemology

Comment: *rasicō is the reconstructed 1st person singular present indicative of the verb with reconstructed infinitive *rāsicāre so these point to the same presumed word

Answer (score 0):

Via [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=rascal+etymology), I found:

> rascal (n.)
> mid-14c., rascaile "people of the lowest class, the general mass; rabble or foot-soldiers of an army" (senses now obsolete), also singular, "low, tricky, dishonest person," from Old French rascaille "rabble, mob" (12c., Modern French racaille), as Cotgrave's French-English Dictionary (1611) defines it: "the rascality or base and rascall sort, the scumme, dregs, offals, outcasts, of any company."
>
> This is of uncertain origin, perhaps a diminutive from Old French rascler, from Vulgar Latin *rasicare "to scrape" (see rash (n.)) on the notion of "the scrapings." "[U]sed in objurgation with much latitude, and often, like rogue, with slight meaning" [Century Dictionary]. Used also in Middle English of animals unfit to chase as game on account of some quality, especially a lean deer. Also formerly an adjective.

Source: https://www.etymonline.com/word/rascal